# How to get windows 8 metro app element properties

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am going to automate windows metro app using C# UI Automation. How to get windows 8 metro app element  properties. (Is there any tool to get the properties ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the elements present in your UI by using 'inspect.exe' that comes bundled with the Windows Kit. More information on this here - http://guriyakalyani.blogspot.in/2013/05/metro-apps-automation.html